# How To Save The Replace - Python

Tags: python, replace

This is what I am using. It runs everytime the user enters something, and it will replace part of the string, but on the second repeat it goes back to how it was eg

first run of it:

t3st

second run:

te5t

I want both of them to stay so after it would be t35t

```
if ((letterPair) in (allPairs)):
    print ("Correct")
    iReplace = open("textfile.txt")
    iReplace = iReplace.read()
    iReplace = iReplace.replace((letterPair[1]),(letterPair[0]))
    print (iReplace)
    options()
else:
    print ("Incorrect letter pairing")
    options()
```

Comment: Why do you have all those parenthesis in the `if` statement?

Comment: you are rereading `iReplace` each time which resets it.  You then apply the one pair replacement and print

Comment: @cmd how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines need to be moved outside of whatever loop you're using to process input:

```
iReplace = open("textfile.txt")
iReplace = iReplace.read()
```

As your code stands now, you are re-reading the original string from `textfile.txt` every time the user presses a key, and then assigning it to iReplace.

You haven't pasted enough code in to be sure, but I assume there is some sort of loop around the code you posted. Put those lines outside of that.